# Correct return values for rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; (IOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, opengl-es

Can anyone let me know what the function

```
rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

is supposed to return as width and height for the different iOS devices?  I am sure the values I am getting are wrong since moving to latest xcode and ios 8.1

For ipad air I am getting 1024 x 768 and for iphone 5s I am getting 480x320 both of which are obviously NOT the resolutions of the mainScreen. I only have these two devices and the the function USED to return the correct resolutions on previous sdk/xcode. My code relies heavily on these values being correct in order to automate positioning and scale of UI, openGL render buffers etc, and now that is broken thanks to this function returning bad values.

Comment: 1024x768 is the correct size for an iPad (in landscape). 480x320 indicates your iPhone is in landscape but is seems you don't have the 4" launch image which is why you get 480 instead of 568.

Comment: I am using an iPad air which is 2048x1536, shouldn't that be the returned value for h and w?

Comment: No. All iPads have a screen size of 1024x768. This is in points, not pixels. View measurements are always in points. If you want the screen size in pixels, multiple by the screen scale.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  One last thing, how do I get the screen scale of the device that you mention above?

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIScreen`.

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy comments, UIKit has always reported screen and view dimensions in points—a unit of UI layout whose size is (roughly) constant across devices—not pixels. (And he's also correct that you'll see only the 3.5" iPhone size unless you've added launch image resources for 4", 4.7", and 5.5" screens.)

To get an OpenGL ES framebuffer with the native resolution of the display, multiply the point size by the screen's [`nativeScale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/nativeScale) factor.  Or get the [`nativeBounds`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/nativeBounds) directly. But it might be best to just use [`GLKView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKView_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GLKView) to get all the framebuffer stuff done for you (and done right) automatically.

Note that `nativeScale` And `nativeBounds` are new `UIScreen` properties in iOS 8 — it's the only way to get the non-integral pixel scale of the iPhone 6 Plus rather than the 3x scale UIKit uses for art. On previous iOS versions (where you don't have to worry about iPhone 6 Plus), you can still use `scale` and `bounds`.

Comment: Thanks Rickster, The correct resolution issue is solved, but I am getting a very odd anomaly with iOS8 where my screen is rendered 25% up to the left... I check all the values coming from bounds etc and all seems correct. My project is based on the old EAGLview code, and I have tried using xib (which USED to work fine) and also tried generating the window myself. I always get the same result. The screen is shifted 25% up to the left (along with the touch area). Its quite baffling.

Comment: If it helps I am running my game in landscape mode.

Comment: That's a separate issue, so it's best posted as a separate question.